# In Production Web App Giving Parse Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

My problem is that my company's website has recently been getting the following parse error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request.      Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'namespace.Index'.

Source Error: 

Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="namespace.Index" CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "..." />


Source File: /Index.aspx    Line: 1
```

Now this website has been running just fine for a while with the last code changes about two months ago. In the past 2 weeks though this is the third time the parse error has appeared. I have fixed it each time by rebuilding the project in visual studios and publishing it, but in a few days it comes back. I have no idea what is causing this error, as I said there have been no code changes in the past 2 months.  Does anyone know what could be causing the parse error to appear?

EDIT: Not sure if this will help but all the HTML pages of the site still show up no problem even when this error is occurring on the asp pages. Also this error has occurred 5 times and now it seems to take 2 or 3 re-publishes of the site before the site will comeback up.

Comment: Is the code-behind class `namespace.Index` perhaps `internal` ? It should probably be `public`...

Comment: Probably when you are republishing, the effect that fixes the error is restarting the application, rather than republishing. Perhaps there is a memory leak? Check for undisposed resources that need to be disposed, like database connections, command objects, data readers.

Comment: Interesting... What version of IIS / Server OS are you using?

Comment: No the code behind class is not internal its in a the .aspx.cs file and im not sure of os of the server but i think it is running apache as it uses the .htaccess file

Comment: The site is being hosted on bellhosting so i don't know if the site tells you what the os of the server is.

Comment: as far as I have seen all database connections have a try catch with a finally that closes and disposes the objects but I will keep looking

Comment: The next time it happens, you could just make a whitespace change to the web.config file and save it.  That will force the recycling of the app.  If it works, that would seem to confirm @jamietre's suspicions.

Comment: @Ben, do you ever pass datareaders as parameters to methods? I've gotten into trouble this way before, if you ever use datareaders outside a using() block it's easy to lose them. Also, ensure you have CommandBehavior.CloseConnection as a parameter for all database commands or explicitly dispose of them.

Comment: @jamietre, there were some database items that were only closed and not disposed of which have been fixed, and yes I did have a couple methods where passed a datareader. Those now have the close and dispose on them. Hopefully this fixes the problem.

Comment: @RQDQ thanks ill keep that in mind. The only thing that doesn't make sense to me about the memory leaks is that the website was fine for about 2 months before the error and there hasn't been any increase of traffic on the site or anything to cause 3 errors in such a short amount of time.

Comment: @RQDQ @jamietre well it took a mere 16 hours for the site to go down again but it did. I tried adding the whitespace and i added a few comments just incase to the web.config and .htaccess files but it did not fix the problem.

Comment: Missed your followup comment from Feb 18, that surprises me, ugh. Did you figure anything else out in the last week? And what's 'htaccess'? :) Isn't this IIS?

Comment: my guess would be some external source mangling the compiled code, can you see if the files have been updated since you last published?

Comment: I don't know how I missed this before but in your 2/17 comment you say "I think it's running apache??" I kinda think all bets are off if you are running this under apache (I guess with `mod_aspdotnet`? which appears to be unsupported and not in active development). Who knows if editing web.config would cause a restart in this environment, among other possible issues. I'd start by ensuring you are running your asp.net web site under iis :)

Comment: I'm not sure what it is running anymore. I have some redirects on the site that are in the .htaccess file which is originally why I thought it was apache, but while configuring the ELMAH that tony suggested I had to modify the web.config file and those changes took effect. So maybe it uses iis that also uses a .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to solve these weird and obscure errors doing one, a combination or all three of the following:

- ELMAH
- HealthMonitoring
- Try/Catch around every piece of code to try and isolate

ELMAH and HM catch different errors and they catch them differently. The try/catch allows you to isolate the code. Onbviously, the try/catch is reasonable if you have an idea of where the problem is - one page, data access, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the info I will definitely try ELMAH and health monitoring out to see if the can help find what is causing the problems. All data access code already have try/catchs on them that send an error email if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running any anti-virus software on the server? If so can you exclude the web app's directory?

I would also recommend using fuslogvw (part of the .NET SDK) to see if there are any assembly binding failures.

Comment: There is no anti-virus software running on the server to my knowledge. If there is it is bell the hosting company who is running it. I used fuslogvw and I checked all the entries and they were all completed successfully.